# Error in htaccess with RewriteRule

Tags: php, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I have this code in my .htacces

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ index.php?modo=$1&tipo=$2&poblacion=$3
```

And when I go to myweb.com/first-text/second-text/third-text nad this show me

The following error occurred:
The requested URL caused an internal server error.

If you get this message repeatedly please contact the webmaster.

Comment: what url did you try to fetch?

Comment: I whant to open the index.php with that three parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following Rules in .htaccess file:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$ index.php?modo=$1&tipo=$2&poblacion=$3 [L]
```

Then you can use the url as:-

```
myweb.com/modoValue/tipoValue/poblacionValue
```

Comment: I also opened with Notepad++ and save it again with the codification UTF-8 without BOM